# Replace link and redirect with javascript ( json , api )

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to replace link from api, and redirect automatically to another link

**Html code :**

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="link"></p>
<script>
$.getJSON('api_url', function(data) {
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = data.url;
}); 
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Api Result :**

```
<p id="link"></p>  

//example1.com/aaa/?k=0000
```

**I want to replace this link**

```
//example1.com/aaa/
```

**With**

```
//aaa.com/aaa/
```

And

**Redirect to**

```
https://aaa.com/aaa/?k=0000
```

Comment: ok, then what is the problem?

Comment: hello Sir @Ravi  , How can i do that?  with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello did you try this below ?

```
var url = "//example1.com/aaa/?k=0000";
var url = url.replace("//example1.com/aaa/", "//aaa.com/aaa/");

window.location="https:"+url;
```

to get the link from your api result you can use :

```
var url = document.getElementById("link").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you @Aotoki , how can i print api result from id .. <p id="link"></p> in your code .. var url =

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
    $.getJSON('api_url', function(data) {
      var link=document.getElementById("link");
          link.setAttribute('href', data.url);
          link.click();
    });
```